# Can the Swift compiler create a single executable for my application?

Tags: swift, vapor

I'm currently trying to create an executable for my Vapor application, but I just can't run it on my server.

My expectation was that it would be able to create a single application with all my code and the dependencies. My current references are .NET and Go, where you can create a single executable from the code and deploy this standalone file - which makes it amazingly simple to deploy.

I tried compiling and executing it on Docker, but no such luck - it failed with some libSwift something missing.

So, can Swift do something like this?

Looking forward to your answers

Comment: Have you tried 'swiftc' in Terminal?  Used at prompt like this: swiftc fileName.swift -o myExecutable

Comment: Yes you can deploy just one executable swift binary, but it should be compiled exactly in the same environment where it will be executed cause it expects to find all the dependencies exactly where they were linked during compilation. So create a docker image for compilation, then same image for execution and before execution install all needed environment/dependencies which are listed on swift.org

Comment: Ok, this makes sense, but Go and .NET binaries are literally stand-alone. They have zero external dependencies, as in no need to find any file outside the binary that is generated. Is it possible to make something similar, in Swift?

Answer (score 5):

You can build a binary that statically links the standard library or build a completely self contained binary using the static linking flags introduced in Swift 5.3.1 - `-static-stdlib` and `-static-executable`. See [this forum post](https://forums.swift.org/t/static-linking-on-linux-in-swift-5-3-1/41989) for more details.

Note that swift still has some dependencies on ICU and libc so aren't completely portable yet

Comment: error: -static-stdlib is no longer supported for Apple platforms :(

Comment: You can't build it for apple platforms because the OS ships with Swift. It only works on Linux and windows